# Deploying Delphi MySQL database to run on Linux Ubuntu / Android

Tags: mysql, linux, delphi, deployment

I have already created a small `MySQL` / `Delphi 11.3` based database and application that runs under Windows 11.  This is for use by a small charitable organisation.  The database is stored on a cloud based server(FreeDB) for development purposes.  The windows based application requires no installation to speak of, just supply the executable and libmysql.dll in the executables folder.  There are no issues with the connectivity and all works fine on every PC I have tried it on.  However not all of the users have Windows based PC's or laptops and there is a need to compile for Linux and Android devices

When I compile for use on `Linux`, the compilation works just fine, the executable is ported across to my virtual machine via paserver but refuses to run. (Other non mysql apps run just fine so paserver is working correctly)

I am no expert on Linux but am assuming that just as Windows requires libmysql.dll, in order to access the mysql database, Linux will also have some dependencies in order to gain access as well.  I have looked at several solutions including installing MYSQL on the Linux VM.  Nothing seems to work for me at the moment.

Any help with deployment to linux would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need libmysqlclient.so on your linux machine. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC).

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient21
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
```

Note that the current version is 21, not 20 as shown in the reference.